# groupby first on NaT not like NaN in groupby

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame where I want to use the groupby method first to collect the first time stamp of each column.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime as dt

ts1 = dt.datetime.now()
ts2 = dt.datetime.now()
ts3 = dt.datetime.now()

DFdate=DataFrame([{'timestamp1':ts1,'ID':'A'},{'timestamp2':ts2,'ID':'A'},{'timestamp3':ts3,'ID':'A'}])
```

Generates a data frame as this where missing time stamps are replaced by NaT:

```
  ID              timestamp1              timestamp2              timestamp3
0  A 2015-07-12 23:19:38.044                     NaT                     NaT
1  A                     NaT 2015-07-12 23:19:38.044                     NaT
2  A                     NaT                     NaT 2015-07-12 23:19:38.044
```

Then executing the groupby first method on this data frame:

```
DFdate.groupby('ID').first()
```

unexpectedly to me generates a data frame like this where the NaT is selected as first value of the columns where they appear before the timestamp:

```
                timestamp1 timestamp2 timestamp3
ID                                              
A  2015-07-12 23:19:38.044        NaT        NaT
```

My expectation was to get something below where each column has the first non NaT value of the columns in the original data frame.

```
                timestamp1                timestamp2                timestamp3
ID                                              
A  2015-07-12 23:19:38.044   2015-07-12 23:19:38.044   2015-07-12 23:19:38.044
```

The below shows shows that NaN is not used in in the result of the groupby first method.

```
DFnum=DataFrame([{'Num1':1,'ID':'A'},{'Num2':2,'ID':'A'},{'Num3':3,'ID':'A'}])
```

Results in this data frame:

```
  ID  Num1  Num2  Num3
0  A     1   NaN   NaN
1  A   NaN     2   NaN
2  A   NaN   NaN     3
```

Executing the groupby first method generates the expected result (no NaN in the result):

```
DFnum.groupby('ID').first()

    Num1  Num2  Num3
ID                  
A      1     2     3
```

Shouldn't groupby first use only real time stamps and skip the NaT:s?

I am using Pandas version 0.16.2

Answer (score 1):

The result of `DFnum` is actually a bit surprise to me, because I thought `.first()` behaves exactly the same as `.head(1)` so returning a first row of grouped dataframe `1 NaN NaN` is what I expect.

Nevertheless, to get want you want for `DFdate` (the first `non-null` value for each column), you can try the following code.

```
DFdate.groupby('ID').agg(lambda col: col[col.notnull()].values[0])


                   timestamp1                 timestamp2                 timestamp3
ID                                                                                 
A  2015-07-12 23:08:26.336435 2015-07-12 23:08:26.336581 2015-07-12 23:08:26.336741
```

Comment: As you mentioned the use of `head(1)` I notice that.

`DFdate.groupby('ID').agg(lambda col: col[col.notnull()].head(1))`
also seems give the same result.

Comment: @Wurdius Yes, `head(1)` on each column also gives the same result.